# Why doesn't my awk pattern match the configure arguments of nginx -V?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to get just the configure arguments of compiled nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 using a command line.

Running `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V` gives us:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.1
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --add-module=/usr/local/src/nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng-c78b7dd79d0d --with-http_sub_module
```

Which makes sense.

So now I want to cut this line to have just:

> --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --add-module=/usr/local/src/nginx-goodies-nginx-sticky-module-ng-c78b7dd79d0d --with-http_sub_module

After looking online, it seems like either

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V | sed -n -e '/arguments/ s/.*\: *//p'
```

or

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V | awk -F":" '{print $NF}'
```

or

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V | egrep -o '\\-\\-'
```

But they all just output the same as `nginx -V`

What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Doesn't the output go to stderr? In such case, you need to redirect the output: `nginx -V 2>&1 | sed ...`

Comment: Since there seems to be a fixed number of colons, `cut` would work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's  `:` used on each line , so you can treat line as several parts separated by `:`, and in your case you want 2nd field where `configure arguments` string appears:

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V  2>&1 | awk -F ':' '/configure arguments/{print $2}'
```

As was mentioned in the comments under the question, the output of `-V`  goes to the error stream, so we had to make it go to the `stdout` stream  ( which is what `2>&1` does)

Comment: This just prints a lot of white space for some reason. Doing $2 instead gives the options plus the version and a lot of white space in between:

Comment: @Seraphim  Can you post full output of that  `nginx -V` command to paste.ubuntu.com ? I don't have nginx on my system right now

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/19162022/

Comment: @Seraphim ah, so there is more output than just one line ! OK, I will fix the command.

Comment: Thats the thing, on the box it appears as one line, but when I copy it or use grep, it behaves as just one linie!

Comment: @Seraphim How is this `awk -F ':' '/configure arguments/{print $2}' ` ?

Comment: @Seraphim OK, I have edited it back into my answer. The output on command line works as multiple lines, so we had to find line with `configure arguments` first, which is what modification does.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that the output goes to the standard error. You need to redirect it:

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -n -e '/arguments/ s/.*\: *//p'
#                              ~~~~
```